# python - format multiline string with % dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a multiline string (big mysql query) and I want to format it with dictionary (data) like this:

```
query = """
        INSERT LOW_PRIORITY INTO goods(id, type, volume, strength,
        country, price, description, year, image, url, class, color,
        grape, vintage, dryness, shop, added)
        VALUES (
        '%(id)s',
        '%(type)s',
        '%(volume)s',
        %(strength)d,
        '%(country)s',
        %(price)d,
        '%(description)s',
        '%(year)s',
        '%(image)s',
        '%(url)s',
        '%(class)s',
        '%(color)s',
        '%(grape)s',
        %(vintage)d,
        '%(dryness)s',
        '%(shop)s',
        '%(added)s'
        ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        type = '%(type)s',
        volume = '%(volume)s',
        strength = %(strength)d,
        country = '%(country)s',
        price = %(price)d,
        description = '%(description)s',
        year = '%(year)s',
        image = '%(image)s',
        url = '%(url)s',
        class = '%(class)s',
        color = '%(color)s',
        grape = '%(grape)s',
        vintage = %(vintage)d,
        dryness = '%(dryness)s',
        shop = '%(shop)s',
        added = '%(added)s""" % data
```

When I'm trying to do this I didn't get any error, but my string dissappears. Is there any way to solve this task?

**UPDATE:**
I have found the problem. I've tried to format ascii string with unicode values of my dictionary. I haven't seen traceback because of try/except block, from which my method with query execution has been called. **Moral of the story is: always check string encoding in Python 2.x**

Comment: You should not be doing this with pure string manipulation; your input will not be properly escaped. `MySQLdb` supports [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) which specifies: `cursor.execute(operation, parameters)`.

Comment: Looks promising, but I can't find an example with dict. Could you please point me on it?

Comment: [Some examples](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples), e.g. `c.execute("INSERT INTO breakfast (name, spam, eggs, sausage, price) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", ["Spam and Sausage Lover's Plate", 5, 1, 8, 7.95])`

Comment: In this example you pass list of tuples while I have a dictionary.

Comment: That is why this is a comment and not an answer. If you use your current method, your data will not be properly escaped.

Comment: It is preferable nowadays to use the `.format()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "disappears"? If you issue `print query`, what is returned?
It looks like you missed a single quote on the last line: shouldn't it be `added = '%(added)s'""" % data`

Comment: Thanks for missed quote. By "disappears" I mean that if I'll remove %data and call "print query" it will be printed successfully, but with %data query doesn't prints at all

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your data dict is missing some key.

For example:

```
In [1]: "%(xx)s" % dict()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/<redacted>/<ipython-input-1-475612d1eaa2> in <module>()
----> 1 "%(xx)s" % dict()

KeyError: 'xx'
```